# How set parameters in SQL Server table from Copy Data Activity - Source: XML / Sink: SQL Server Table / Mapping: XML column

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-sql-server

I have a question, hopefully someone in the forum could give some help here. I am able to pull data from Soap API call to SQL Server table (xml data type field actually) via Copy Data Activity. The pipeline that runs this process is metadata driven, so how could I write other parameters in the same SQL Server table for the same run? I am using a Copy Data Activity to load XML data to SQL Server table but in Mapping tab I am not able to select other parameters in order to point them to others SQL table columns.

In addition, I am using a ForEach Activity in order the Copy Data Activity iterates for several values of one column on SQL Server table.

I will appreciate any advice on this.

Thanks
David

Thank you for your interest, I will try to be more explicit with this image: Hopefully this clarify a little bit. Given the current escenario, how could I pass StoreId and CustomerNumber parameters to the table Stage.XmlDataTable?

Taking in to account in the mapping step I am just able to map XML data from the current API call and then write it into Stage.XmlDataTable - XmlData column.

Thanks in advance David

[image]

Comment: I’m not sure I fully understand, maybe more of a worked example would help, eg you have this xml, this table you want to populate these columns etc. However, how about landing your xml in an intermediate table and using a subsequent  Stored Proc activity to add the other columns on INSERT to the main table.  Or maybe even a stored proc Sink?  It can be fiddly setting up the table types but could work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your parameters using Additional Columns in the `Copy data` activity Source.

[image]

When you import schema in mapping you can see the additional columns added in source.

[image]

Refer to this MS document for more details on [adding additional columns during the copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#add-additional-columns-during-copy).

Comment: That is correct, that info was very helpful, just saved my day..!!